# navigation view item is getting shifted to right

Tags: android, colors, menu, navigation-drawer, menuitem

i added a layout file as a menu item in navigation view, the problem is the item is placed at the right

here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="start">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/home"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/accueil"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/White_Flight"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

here is the menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


  <group>
    
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_accueil"
        android:title=""
        app:actionLayout="@layout/home_menu_item"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_agenda"
        android:title="@string/agenda"
        android:icon="@drawable/remove"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_maps"
        android:title="@string/maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/remove"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_scanner"
        android:title="@string/scanner_qrcode"
        android:icon="@drawable/remove"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_reserve"
        android:title="@string/confirmer_participation"
        android:icon="@drawable/remove"/>

</group>

</menu>
```

finaly here is the navigationview in the main xml file

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/participant_menu"/>
```

so how can i place it at the start, or even better how to change the color of the other items

[image: here is screen shot off the result of the current code]

Comment: You want to move your first menu item to left, is that right?

Comment: @Rajasekhar tes, exactly, and i also want to change the color of other items

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set your custom view's width to match parent , it should look like :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="start">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/home"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/accueil"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/White_Flight"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, i tried that, but it didn't work, thank you for the help tho